# Injected Javascript into WebView, Android not loading, React Native & Expo SDK

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I am working with the Expo SDK and want to display an Intercom Chat via Expo-WebView since Intercom only supports native Apps.
I managed to make it work on IOS, however Android wont boot up and only display me a the blue background. Any ideas?

Expo version 48.0
React Native 0.72
react-native-webview 11.26

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import WebView, { WebViewMessageEvent } from 'react-native-webview';
import { LoadingSpinner } from '~components/styled/LoadingSpinner';
import { COLORS } from '~styles/theme';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import {
  registerForPushNotificationsAsync,
  sendPushNotification,
} from '../../utils/PushNotification';

export const IntercomWebView: FunctionComponent<{
  uuid: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}> = ({ uuid, email, firstName, lastName }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState<string>('');
  const [, setNotification] = useState<Notifications.Notification>();
  const notificationListener = useRef<Notifications.Subscription>();
  const responseListener = useRef<Notifications.Subscription>();

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => {
      if (token) {
        setExpoPushToken(token.data);
      }
    });

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
      if (notification) {
        setNotification(notification);
      }
    });

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
    });

    return () => {
      if (notificationListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
      }
      if (responseListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const inject = `
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '[aria-label="Close"] { display: none !important; }';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    window.Intercom('boot', {
      api_base: 'intercom-url',
      app_id: 'intercom-id',
      email: "${email}",
      name: "${firstName} ${lastName}",
      user_id: "${uuid}",
    });
    true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
  `;

  const handlePushNotification = useCallback((event: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
    const notificationData = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
    const { title, message } = notificationData;
    sendPushNotification(expoPushToken, title, message);
  }, [expoPushToken]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner size="small" />}
      <WebView
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.Blue }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{
          html: `<!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title>Intercom Chat</title>
                <script>
                  (function(){
                    var w=window;
                    var ic=w.Intercom;
                    if(typeof ic==="function"){
                      ic('reattach_activator');
                      ic('update',w.intercomSettings);
                    }else{
                      var d=document;
                      var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};
                      i.q=[];
                      i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};
                      w.Intercom=i;
                      var l=function(){
                        var s=d.createElement('script');
                        s.type='text/javascript';
                        s.async=true;
                        s.src='intercom-url';
                        var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);
                      };
                      if(document.readyState==='complete'){
                        l();
                      }else if(w.attachEvent){
                        w.attachEvent('onload',l);
                      }else{
                        w.addEventListener('load',l,false);
                      }
                    }
                  })();
                </script>
              </head>
              <body>
                <script>
                  (function(){
                    window.Intercom('show');
                  })();
                </script>
              </body>
            </html>`,
        }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
        injectedJavaScript={inject}
        injectedJavaScriptForMainFrameOnly={true}
        onMessage={(event) => {}}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

I currently tried all the available properties on the WebView Component:

```js
        setDomStorageEnabled={true}
        setLoadWithOverviewMode={true}
        setUseWideViewPort={true}
        setBuiltInZoomControls={true}
        setDisplayZoomControls={false}
        setSupportZoom={true}
        setJavaScriptEnabled={true}
        setDefaultTextEncodingName={'utf-8'}
```

Set permissions in app.config.ts:

```
android: {
    permissions: ['INTERNET'],
```

and also tried to load any url via uri source - which worked so far.

My guess is, that Android somehow can't handle the injected Javascript.

Comment: There is a much cleaner and easier way of installing intercom with expo using official `@intercom/intercom-react-native` package. You just need to use the development build and a custom-plugin for adding some configurations during the syncing phase of expo-prebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set `baseUrl` in WebView source property to `'https://widget.intercom.io/'`.
So your `source` would be:

```
source={{html: YourHtml, baseUrl: 'https://widget.intercom.io/' }}
```

hope it helps.